# libre/open office macros problem - presentation api

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

(i copied that part from askubuntu) from 2 days i'm trying to make a macro to execute presentation from second slide without yet fullscreening that. base code i'm using to try any possible methods is:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Sub execute
Dim Doc As Object 
Dim Presentation As Object 
Dim SlideList As Object
Dim Slide As Object
Doc = ThisComponent
Presentation = Doc.Presentation
SlideList = Doc.getDrawPages()
Slide = SlideList.getByName("2")
Presentation.start(IsFullScreen(), IsAlwaysOnTop(), Slide(), IsMouseVisible(), )
end sub
```

presentation is always starting... but not from second slide. when trying method from official libreoffice site (https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Presentations) it also doesn't work (it starts from first slide, even if i make not `FirstSlide` but `SecondSlide`). trying to defining slide by index creates errors that they're not defined. is there any way to make it work?

PS: i can't use java because of a system failure, so i need to write in VBA.

Comment: Yes, you're right - this code is not causing the presentation to start, but a headache. How do you trying to get the second slide by number? By the way, the line `SlideList.getByName("2")` will only work if you manually set the name for the second slide "2", usually something like "Slide2". And the line `Presentation.start(IsFullScreen (), etc.` will not work at all - the Start method has no parameters, everything that you wrote in parentheses does not matter. Perhaps you need the `.startWithArguments()` method. How to use it correctly? I'm not ready to tell, this requires additional research.

Comment: i setted name as 2. anyways - your code throws this: https://ibb.co/khVcVD8

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this

```
Sub RunFromSecondSlide
Dim oPresentation As Variant
Dim oDrawPages As Variant
    oPresentation = ThisComponent.getPresentation()
    oDrawPages = ThisComponent.getDrawPages()
    oPresentation.FirstPage = oDrawPages.getByIndex(1).getName()    
    oPresentation.start()
End Sub
```

Comment: thx! worked! (i even didn't thought about setting first as second page :'D)

Comment: edit: but now it doesn't enter in fullscreen mode with mouse...

Comment: With mouse? Why not with `oPresentation.IsFullScreen=True` before `.start()`?

Comment: it just thrown some errors... here you have crash : https://ibb.co/pK4kRRw

Comment: Sorry, I should have written more clearly: before the `oPresentation.start()` line, you can set the value of any presentation parameter, for example `oPresentation.IsFullScreen = True`. (Of course, boolean TRUE does not have a `start()` method.)

Comment: doesn't work, starts in a window (toolbar visible, mouse vanishing OFTEN) + button i created for macro is visible on other slides when trying to make a printscreen...

Comment: I didn’t understand - did you need a hint about starting a presentation from the second slide or a complete listing of a program that should do something known only to you with a presentation that only you can see? For me, the code I provided works correctly - it opens the slideshow from the second slide in full screen mode. Perhaps you should ask your questions on some forum - the format of this resource does not provide for long discussions

Comment: i've figured out it by myself - code i should made was : 
`Sub RunFromSecondSlide
Dim oPresentation As Variant
Dim oDrawPages As Variant
oPresentation = ThisComponent.getPresentation()
oDrawPages = ThisComponent.getDrawPages()
oPresentation.FirstPage = oDrawPages.getByIndex(1).getName()    
oPresentation.IsFullScreen=True
oPresentation.IsAlwaysOnTop=True
oPresentation.IsMouseVisible=true
oPresentation.StartWithNavigator=False
oPresentation.start()
End Sub
`
and then to open second in fullscreen i needed to dblClick my button. anyways - you helped me :) thx

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how to make it work, code here:

```
Sub RunFromSecondSlide
Dim oPresentation As Variant
Dim oDrawPages As Variant
    oPresentation = ThisComponent.getPresentation()
    oDrawPages = ThisComponent.getDrawPages()
    oPresentation.FirstPage = oDrawPages.getByIndex(1).getName()    
    oPresentation.IsFullScreen=True
    oPresentation.IsAlwaysOnTop=True
    oPresentation.IsMouseVisible=true
    oPresentation.StartWithNavigator=False
    oPresentation.start()
End Sub
```

and then i needed to double click created by myself button (single click shows slide where i neede to click again)